# What pin is the select pin sd

Tags: pi-2

Hi I've got raspberry pi 2 and wondering which pin is ss on the pi using bcm numbering as I'm trying to connect uart but I'm not sure Which pin is the ss pin anyone help please thx

Comment: Welcome to RPI.StackExchange! UART does not use SS, it uses TX (BCM 14) and RX (BCM 15) pins.

Comment: Just out of interest Whitch pin is the ss

Comment: Sorry it's not uart I'm using its sclk. Miso and mosi then ss but I don't know which is ss sorry I got mixed up thx

Comment: Sorry are you looking for the 'Chip Select' pin for SPI or similar?

Answer (score 1):

Recent Pis (40 pin expansion header) and the compute module have two SPI devices.

The main SPI device has two slave selects (chip enable on the Pi) on GPIO 8 and 7.

The auxiliary SPI device has three slave selects on GPIO 18, 17, and 16.

```
           pin  pin
3V3         1    2      5V
0/2 (SDA)   3    4      5V
1/3 (SCL)   5    6      0V
4           7    8      14 (TXD)
0V          9   10      15 (RXD)
17 (ce1)   11   12      18 (ce0)
21/27      13   14      0V
22         15   16      23
3V3        17   18      24
10 (MOSI)  19   20      0V
9 (MISO)   21   22      25
11 (SCLK)  23   24      8 (CE0)
0V         25   26      7 (CE1)
           .......
0 (ID_SD)  27   28      1 (ID_SC)
5          29   30      0V
6          31   32      12
13         33   34      0V
19 (miso)  35   36      16 (ce2)
26         37   38      20 (mosi)
0V         39   40      21 (sclk)
```